# Is there a simpler syntax for member decorators for methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I changed a `class` which had a function that had to be ran prior to running a number of other functions.  The "prior-to-others" function is now a decorator.  But the syntax, which I came up with, seems very unintuitive.

It used to be something like this:

```
class Session:
    def __init__(self, ts):
        self.tempo_throttlers = [TempoThrottler(t) for t in ts]
        ...

    def _wait_on_throttlers(self):
        for th in self.tempo_throttlers:
            if not th.isallowed():
                time.sleep(th.mustwait())
            th.consume()
        ...

    def request1(self):
        self._wait_on_throttlers()
        ...

    def request2(self):
        self._wait_on_throttlers()
        ...
```

And now it's like this:

```
class Session:
    def __init__(self, ts):
        self.tempo_throttlers = [TempoThrottler(t) for t in ts]
        ...

    def _wait_on_throttlers(self):
        for th in self.tempo_throttlers:
            if not th.isallowed():
                time.sleep(th.mustwait())
            th.consume()
        ...

    def _throttled(f):
        def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self._wait_on_throttlers()
            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return inner

    @_throttled
    def request1(self):
        ...

    @_throttled
    def request2(self):
        ...
```

And, while I think the use of this decorator made the code more clear, the implementation of this decorator took some doing.  It's also very fragile and hard to read.  For example, if the inner return line `return f(self, *args, **kwargs)` is changed to `return self.f(*args, **kwargs)`, then it won't work anymore.

This seems to do with the order in which the elements of the class are compiled.  I am also afraid that this would break in future versions of Python.  I am using Python 3.6.8.

Is there an accepted and/or recommended way to make such class-member decorators of class methods which would be less counter-intuitive and less fragile?

*For the sake of a minimal reproducible **example***, the `...` can be considered to be a `pass` statement and the class `TempThrottler` can be defined as below (this isn't the actual implementation, but it's enough to satisfy the example above):

```
class TempoThrottler:
    def __init__(self, t):
        pass
    def isallowed(self):
        from random import randint
        return (True, False)[randint(0,1)]
    def mustwait(self):
        return 1
    def consume(self):
        pass
```

Comment: The decorators don't have to be in the class, so moving them out of it might improve things.

Comment: It should break if you change `f(self, ...)` to `self.f(...)`. `f` is a reference to the function in the first case but an attribute in the second, and since `self` doesn't have an attribute `'f'`, it errors.

Comment: @martineau the decorator uses the objects's data.  Its whole point is to call wait_on_throttlers.  The state of the throttling of the session is part of the state of the session.

Comment: Since it's calling `_wait_on_throttlers()` via its `self` argument, it doesn't need to be within the body of the class to do it. It would be a problem if it were using anything defined in the class but not passed to it as an argument.

Comment: @martineau the state of throttling is part of the data of a session.  If I move `_wait_on_throttlers` outside of the class, I would have to pass the session data to the decorator somehow or it wouldn't be possible for the decorator to pass that data to its call to `_wait_on_throttlers`.  I *did* try pulling the decorator out, but I couldn't figure it out.  I'll add a bit more of the code to the question.  If you have an idea of how to pull the decorator out, please, post an answer.

Comment: If you can provide a [mre] I'll try to show you. Just to be clear, I mean move the `_throttled(f)` decorator out of the class. The `_wait_on_throttlers()` method would probably need to say in it (but without real code, it's hard to say).

Comment: @martineau  I've added enough that it should be runnable now.  The `...` do have to be replaced with a `pass` statement though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a runnable example that illustrates my suggestion of how it would be possible to move the decorator function completely out of the class:

```
from random import randint
import time


class TempoThrottler:
    def __init__(self, t):
        pass
    def isallowed(self):
 #       return [True, False](randint(0,1))
        return [True, False][randint(0,1)]
    def mustwait(self):
        return 1
    def consume(self):
        pass


# Decorator not in class.
def _throttled(f):
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._wait_on_throttlers()
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner


class Session:
    def __init__(self, ts):
        self.tempo_throttlers = [TempoThrottler(t) for t in ts]
        ...

    def _wait_on_throttlers(self):
        for th in self.tempo_throttlers:
            if not th.isallowed():
                time.sleep(th.mustwait())
            th.consume()
        ...

    @_throttled
    def request1(self):
        print('in request1()')
        ...

    @_throttled
    def request2(self):
        print('in request2()')
        ...


s = Session(range(3))
s.request1()  # -> in request1()
s.request2()  # -> in request2()
```

Comment: I see I misunderstood your original comment.  This is good.  I didn't actually realize that the fact that it was being defined as a member function was not used inside.

Comment: The decorator is tightly coupled with the class, so IMO putting it in the class would be logical — but as shown, there no requirement for that, and there aren't really any other advantages to doing so making it ultimately just a personal preference.

Comment: To really simplify the syntax—almost get rid of it in fact—you could write a _class_ decorator that automatically decorated the methods of the class it's applied to, provided they can somehow be identified programatically. One simple way to do it by using some sort of naming convention, but there are at least a couple more ways that come to mind.

Comment: I think I am going to get around the fact the decorator is class-specific by making a parametrized decorator, `precall_decorator` that takes a function which is to be pre-called.  And then setting `_throttled = precall_decorator(_wait_on_temp_throttlers)` as a class variables.  This way the `precall_decorator`, which is defined outside of the class, is not coupled with any class.

Answer (score 0):

While this maybe more complicated, at the first glance, in order to address that

1. the decorator is not bound to an instance of the class
2. this decorator is coupled with the class

I am going to make the decorator parametrized and move it outside of the class.  Then the instance of the decorator specialized for a specific pre-call method can be assigned to a class variable.  And then this class variable can be used as the actual decorator.

```
def precall_decorator(precall_f):
    def decor(f):
        def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
            precall_f(self)
            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return inner
    return decor

class Session:
    def __init__(self, ts):
        self.tempo_throttlers = [TempoThrottler(t) for t in ts]
        ...

    def _wait_on_throttlers(self):
        for th in self.tempo_throttlers:
            if not th.isallowed():
                time.sleep(th.mustwait())
            th.consume()
        ...

    _throttled = precall_decorator(_wait_on_throttlers)

    @_throttled
    def request1(self):
        ...

    @_throttled
    def request2(self):
        ...
```